# C#, Bitmap becomes twice bigger, why?

Tags: c#

I've got this code:

```
    public void rotateRocketImage()
    {
        Bitmap b = this.rocketImgOriginal;

            //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
        Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(97,97);

            //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap);

            //move rotation point to center of image
        //g.TranslateTransform(48, 48);

            //rotate
        //g.RotateTransform(this.orient);

            //move image back
        //g.TranslateTransform(-48, -48);

            //draw passed in image onto graphics object
        g.DrawImage(b,0,0);

        this.rocketImg = tempBitmap;
    }
```

which ( with RotateTransform currently disables ) should just make  this.rocketImg equal to this.rocketImg , yet somehow it enlarges the picture almost twice... any ideas what could be causing it?

Thanks!

[image]

edit:
here's the drawing code:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        var tempRocket = new Bitmap( rocket.rocketImg );

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(tempRocket))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(tempRocket, 150, 150);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the original size of the image?

Comment: No idea about your actual problem, but your code is quite lazy with disposing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a resolution parameter in bitmap image.

If your bitmaps have different resolutions you receive the deformation when draw one image on other.

See `HorizontalResolution` and `VerticalResolution` properties and `SetResolution` method of `Bitmap` instance.

Code sample which shows how it work:

```
        int magnificationIndex = 2;

        Bitmap tempRocket = new Bitmap("ccc.bmp");

        Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(97, 97);

        tempBitmap.SetResolution(tempRocket.HorizontalResolution * magnificationIndex,
            tempRocket.VerticalResolution * magnificationIndex);


        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 97, 97);
            g.DrawImage(tempRocket,0,0);
        }

        tempBitmap.Save("result.bmp");
```

Comment: can't seem to find it. where should it be?

Comment: @Rob, I have added details in my answer.

Comment: @Rob, You should set equal resolutions for both Bitmaps

Comment: THANKS! Just added "tempBitmap.SetResolution(72,72);" and it works! Yet strange, that it did change the resolution by itself without it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the problem is with the constructor.
This is a link to the class definition in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx
You should specify either a Graphics object or just set the resolution manualy.

Alternativly, you can just specify the original image in the constructor and the new object will inharit it`s properties.

Answer (score 1):

As you said original size of image is **97 X 97**  but you are drawing it with **150 X 150** which makes it larger.

Comment: No, this 150x150 are coordinated where it is drawn. I tried changing them, same size, just another place.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the control that you are drawing this into has the `SizeMode` set to `Zoom`.

Comment: nope, I'm drawing it onto a form, doesn't seem to have "zoom" anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should review the properties of the rocketImg control. Make sure it doesn't stretch, resize.